# Autocomplete Set Default Value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup

I need to have a default value in my autocomplete in my react app. My problem is when i try to submit it, it still is invalid. Meaning it has no value in it. I need to click the autocomplete and select it again just to make to have the value.

Pls check this codesandbox link [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-formik-material-ui-react-gmc7e?file=/src/index.js)

```
          <Autocomplete
            name="member_status"
            value={values.member_status}
            options={memberStatuses ? memberStatuses : []}
            getOptionLabel={(memberStatus) => memberStatus.name}
            onChange={(e, value) => {
              setFieldValue(
                "member_status",
                value !== null ? value.id : ""
              );
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                label="Member Status"
                name="member_status"
                variant="outlined"
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                helperText={
                  touched.member_status ? errors.member_status : ""
                }
                error={
                  touched.member_status && Boolean(errors.member_status)
                }
              />
            )}
          />
```

Comment: Why `yup.string()`? Shouldn't it be an `object`?

Comment: @bertdida. You might want to edit my codesandbox. Thank you

Comment: Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-formik-material-ui-react-forked-y0suq?file=/src/index.js) out.

Comment: @bertdida. Thanks, by the way, where do you put the  `name="member_status"`, `values={values.member_status}`, in the AutoComplete or the TextField part.

Comment: `name="member_status"` should be on the `TextField`, `value` prop should be on  `AutoComplete`.

Comment: @bertdida. Thanks how about the `onBlur`?

Comment: Because you're doing `<TextField {...params}...`, when you pass `onBlur` to `Autocomplete` it would be forwarded to `TextField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is you are setting the initial value of your `Autocomplete` as an `object`, then you're validating for a `string`.

Changing your `validationSchema` to

```js
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  member_status: yup
    .object()
    .shape({
      id: yup.number(),
      name: yup.string()
    })
    .nullable()
    .required("Select member status")
});
```

and your `Autocomplete`'s `onChange` handler to

```js
...
onChange={(e, value) => {
  setFieldValue("member_status", value); // set the new value to an object, not string
}}
```

should work.

[image: Edit autocomplete-formik-material-ui-react (forked)]

Comment: Thank you. Why is there `nullable()` in  `.nullable()
    .required("Select member status")`?

Comment: That's for when user click the `x` button on our form.

Comment: But there's a `required` after it.

Comment: I set `nullable` to avoid this message from __yup - member_status must be a object type, but the final value was: null. If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as .nullable()__. And when the `value` is `null` it would fallback to `required` validator.

Comment: Oh yeah. How can you remove that kind of error? I need it to be required also. and should be nullable. Thanks

Comment: You need it to be `required` but `nullable`? Please elaborate.

Comment: It just needs to be required.

Comment: I'm not sure if we can remove the `null` erro message without using `nullable`.

Comment: Ok. no problem. Thanks